# How to convert a List of Object type to an array of objects

Tags: java

I have to return array of objects from a method. The objects are initially held in a List of objects type. I am having difficulties in assigning values from list of objects to array of objects. How do I do that. Here is my code:

```
public User[] getUser() {

    User[] users = null;

    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    List<User> users = session.createQuery("from User").list();
    for (Iterator<User> iter = users.iterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) {
        User user = iter.next();
        //Here I need to assign User type object from list to array of objects
    }
    return users; // returning nothing so far
}
```

Comment: just do users.ToArray()...oh...wait...no...nevermind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use List's `toArray` method:

```
return users.toArray(new User[users.size]);
```

Answer (score 4):

Switching back and forth from `List`s to arrays and vice versa can be done with the methods

```
User[] array = users.toArray( new User[usersList.size()] );//from list to array
List<User> usersList = Arrays.asList( userArray );//from array to list
```

See the javadoc ( [List#toArray](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28T%5b%5d%29) and [Arrays#asList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) ) of those methods for more information

Comment: Small typo: `new User(usersList...)` should be `new User[](usersList...)`. I tried to make the edit, but it won't let me make such a small change.

Answer (score 1):

Would this solve your problem?

```
usersList = users.toArray(new User[users.size()]);
```

By the way you're using `users` twice in your code (as array and as list)

Comment: Slight performance thing would be to pass in a `new User[users.size()]` instead. Otherwise, `toArray` will take your newly-allocated, zero-length array, see that it's not big enough, and allocate a second array of proper length. If you use `users.size()` to instantiate the `User[]`, that saves an array allocation.